# UITableViewIndex Grows to Incorrect Bounds Unexpectedly

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a standard UITableView + UISearchDisplayController + UITableViewIndex setup. Everything works like a champ.

Except, under very specific conditions, the index grows too long to display on the screen. Specifically, after ending a search and re-displaying the unfiltered, indexed table, the index **sometimes** grows too long.

More specifically, this doesn't happen if I search then cancel. It only happens if I search, then push a view controller from the search table, then pop that view controller back to the still-searching table, then cancel the search, then **re-search** and then cancel that final search. After the end of the final search the index is too long.

In portrait, the table view is reporting a height of 416 and the index a height of 404 under normal conditions. If I log from `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch` when the index is sized incorrectly, it is reporting a height of 620.

I've tried everything from `setLayout` on the table and the index to manually re-sizing the frame. Nothing works (the manual re-size causes the correct height to be logged, but it doesn't change the display on screen).

I was about to try re-sizing after a delay in case the cancel animation was interfering, but then I realized what an absurd situation I'm in and thought seeking help might be wise...

Comment: How are you building your index?  Is it built in viewWillAppear?

Comment: Are you running some kind of background-task (synchronous), it may block the right UI-behaviour in some rare circumstances.

Comment: Might want to check and see if you have auto-resizing set on your view.

Comment: How do you set the frame of the views and where are you changing the frames? Could you paste the code?

Comment: 1) Does this happen EVERY time you follow the directions you stated?  2) Have you tried playing around with the view's autoresizingMask property?

Answer (score 1):

If you are still having trouble, you might try setting a symbolic breakpoint on -[UITableView setFrame:] and trace where the set frame call is coming from. HTH

Comment: (or possibly -[UITableView setBounds:])

Answer (score 0):

My scenario was a little different from the one posted, but I found a solution that works in my case, so hopefully in the one posted here as well.

I have a UITableView that uses a fetchedResultsController and loads more elements from a server when you reach the end of the tableView. When searching, the fetchedResultsController is filtered down and loads more entries from the server when there is not enough to display.

When the connection returns its results (after hitting "search"), I'm reloading the tableViews (the original one and the searchResultsTableView). Now when you cancel the search and everything is set back to normal I experience the problem from the question. The UITableViewIndex grows to its unexpected bounds.

Since I also experiencing that the UITableView resized to be a lot larger than expected, I played a hunch and it worked for me. In your UITableView subclass (this is ARC/6.1):

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ( self.isSearching )
    {
        // Ensure the correct height of the original tableview while displaying the searchresults-tableview
        // only this will make sure, the height of the UITableViewIndex is set correctly ...
        [UIView animateWithDuration:[[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue] animations:^(){
            CGRect rect = self.tableView.frame;
            rect.size.height -= [self.tableView convertRect:[[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue] fromView:nil].size.height;
            self.tableView.frame = rect;
        }];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ( self.isSearching )
    {
        // Ensure the correct height of the original tableview while displaying the searchresults-tableview
        // only this will make sure, the height of the UITableViewIndex is set correctly ...
        [UIView animateWithDuration:[[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue] animations:^(){
            CGRect rect = self.tableView.frame;
            rect.size.height += [self.tableView convertRect:[[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue] fromView:nil].size.height;
            self.tableView.frame = rect;
        }];
    }
}
```

You might need to tweak this.